# req.params not working in mongoose findOne

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have this function which passes a parameter

```
fetchprofile() {

    let uri = "http://localhost:4000/data/username/" + this.tintin;
    this.axios.post(uri).then(response => {

    this.fname = response.data.fname;
    this.lname = response.data.lname;

     });

    }
```

And this is the route:

```
adnmastroutes.route('/username/:usertin').post(function (req, res) {
console.log('TIN No. of user is:' + req.params.usertin);

adnmastmainmodel.findOne({tin: req.params.usertin}, function (err, user) {

if (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
else {

  console.log(user);
  res.json(user);
} }); });
```

Now in the line

```
console.log('TIN No. of user is:' + req.params.usertin);
```

the passed parameter req.params.usertin has a value.
BUT WHY IS IT IN THE LINE

```
adnmastmainmodel.findOne({tin: req.params.usertin}, function (err, user) {
```

the passed parameter req.params.usertin ha NO value.

(the line:
 adnmastmainmodel.findOne({tin: req.params.usertin}, function (err, user) {
 returns a null response. But when I changed it this way:
 adnmastmainmodel.findOne({tin: '012349876'}, function (err, user) {
 it returns the desired response.)

PLEASE HELP HOW WILL I RESOLVE THIS?

p.s. The value of the parameter this.tintin came from sessionStorage.getItem

Comment: *the passed parameter req.params.usertin ha NO value.* - there's no evidence that this is so. This is impossible in the code you posted.

Comment: because the line "adnmastmainmodel.findOne({tin: req.params.usertin}, function (err, user) { " returns a null response. But when I changed it this way: "adnmastmainmodel.findOne({tin: '012349876'}, function (err, user) { " it returns the desired response.

Comment: What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Could you please post the `console.log(this.tintin)` result from client and 
`console.log('TIN No. of user is:' + req.params.usertin);` from server`?

Comment: *returns a null response* - that's indirect evidence and you made wrong conclusion from it. Proceed from the fact that it's the wrong way. I'm not aware of your DB records, Express setup and exact HTTP request, so I cannot say what the problem could be. Considering that `adnmastmainmodel.findOne({tin: '012349876'}` works, can you debug and confirm that `req.params.usertin` is a string (there's a possibility it's not) and that `req.params.usertin === '012349876'`? I'm positive it's not because otherwise you would get exactly same result as with `adnmastmainmodel.findOne({tin: '012349876'}`.

Comment: @SergiiVorobei console.log(this.tintin) results 012349876 and console.log('TIN No. of user is: ' + req.params.usertin) results TIN No. of user is: 012349876

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)

Comment: that's the error i got

Answer (score 1):

Make sure parameter is string by using the toString() function

```
adnmastmainmodel.findOne({tin: req.params.usertin.toString() }, function (err, user)
```

Comment: Is there a better way for me to do this?